# Add more input fields and show vaules with getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I want to show the values of the input fields. Im currently using `onchange="document.getElementById('Priority').innerHTML = this.value"` for single input fields and it work, i just don't know how to do that with multiple input filed. The user can create as much input fields as needed. I need that in this format

```
<Permission Cooldown="ColldownNumber">PermissionName</Permission>
```

**This is my javascript code**

```
let input_str = {
  title: "Permission",
  forms: [
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "Cooldown",
      class: "col-md-6",
      placeholder: "Cooldown"
    },
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "Permission",
      class: "col-md-6",
      placeholder: "Permission"
    }
  ],
  exportTo:$('#getData')
};

$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".addInput").click(function() {
    build_inputs($(this), input_str);
  });
});
let randId = 1;
function build_inputs(e, configs=false) {
    if(!configs){
        configs = {title:"Slides",forms:[{type:"text",name:"name",class:"form-control mb-2",placeholder:"Enter Data..."}],exportTo:false};
    }
  let ind = $(".adp-slides").length > 0 ? $(".adp-slides").length + 1 : 1;
  let str = `<div id="${configs.title + "-" + ind}" class="row adp-slides"><div class="col-md-10"><div class="form-group"><label><b>${ configs.title } ${ind}</b></label>`;
  configs.forms.forEach(config => {
    str += `<input type="${config.type}" name="${config.name}" id="adpElem${randId}" class="${config.class}" data-rel="${configs.title+"-"+ind}" placeholder="${config.placeholder}">`;
    let currentVal = e
      .parent()
      .siblings()
      .val();
    $("#adpElem" + randId)
      .val(currentVal)
      .focus();
    e.parent()
      .siblings()
      .val("");
    randId++;
  });
  str += `</div></div><div class="col-md-1"><span class="RemovePermission" data-target="${configs.title + "-" + ind}"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span></div></div>`;
  $(".inputWrapper").append(str);
  $(".RemovePermission").click(function() {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-target")).remove();
  });
}
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and paste relevant HTML and script and press TIDY before saving

Comment: Can you select them using `document.geElementByClassName()` and then loop through them?